# Communicating Last Full Week to users

Tags: word-choice, phrases, dates

I'm trying to communcate the idea of 'Last full week'. That is, the most recent Sunday through Saturday range that has totally finished.

```
    October 2014
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
          1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8  9 10 11
12 13 14 15 16 17 18
19 20 21 22 23 24 25
26 27 28 29 30 31
```

Some examples

- At 11:00am on Wednesday the 29th, the last full week is the 19th - 25th.
- At 1:00am on Sunday the 26th, the last full week is the 19th - 25th.

Is there a more clear phrase to represent this concept?

Comment: Are you asking this in the context of writing a user interface? Because there is a whole site dedicated to questions about this: http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Note also that European calendars often start with Monday and not Sunday.

Comment: I think you're looking for "***previous***" (or *preceding*), not "*last*", which is ambiguous and can be interpreted as "*final*".

Answer (score 1):

You are only going to find circumlocutions to express this concept. It's common in English to use expressions like:

> Election Day in the United States is the day set by law for the general elections of public officials. It occurs **on the Tuesday after the first Monday in November** (this does not necessarily mean the "first Tuesday" in a month because the first day of a month can be a Tuesday). ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Election_Day_(United_States)))

Even with the clear words, the Wikipedia author thought it necessary to further clarify with a parenthetical statement. And choster's comment above is one example of the futility of having a single word.

So your answer may be something like

> The last full week within the same month, seven days beginning Sunday at midnight and ending Saturday at midnight.